# How to find all differences across 2 sheets with 2 columns each?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is a bit convoluted, so I'm not sure if there is an easy solution.

I have 2 spreadsheets with data and I want to create a 3rd sheet that only records the differences between the 2.

For example:

Sheet 1

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Lion | 5 |
| Tiger | 10 |
| Bear | 15 |
| Panda | 20 |

Sheet 2

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Lion | 5 |
| Tiger | 10 |
| Bear | 18 |

Result Sheet

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Bear | 15 |
| Panda | 20 |

The result would print out Bear because the value changed from 15 to 18, and it would print out Panda because Panda was not on the second list.

Is this something I can easily do in excel? I've looked at a few videos and other threads but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Here is a screenshot of what is happening for me

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `FILTER()` Function 2 ways.

[image]

---

• Formula can be used in cell `G3`

```
=FILTER(A3:B6,IFNA(((D3:D5=A3:A6)*(E3:E5=B3:B6))<>1,TRUE))
```

---

• Formula can be used in cell `G3`

```
=FILTER(A3:B6,COUNTIFS(D3:D5,A3:A6,E3:E5,B3:B6)=0)
```

---

I realized the 2nd approach will be much more neater than the first one, so I will explain the 2nd one before,

• `COUNTIFS()` function is used to get the number of times all criterias are met.

[image]

```
=COUNTIFS(D3:D5,A3:A6,E3:E5,B3:B6)
```

---

• We can see from above it returns `1` & `0` so the `0's` are those which are not met and we need those, hence doing **Boolean Check** which returns `TRUE` & `FALSE` respectively.

[image]

```
=COUNTIFS(D3:D5,A3:A6,E3:E5,B3:B6)=0
```

---

Last not least to get the required output, wrap it within the `FILTER()`

[image]

```
=FILTER(A3:B6,COUNTIFS(D3:D5,A3:A6,E3:E5,B3:B6)=0)
```

---

A quick explanation on the 1st approach, how the formula works:

• `=(D3:D5=A3:A6)` the Boolean checks for whether there is a match in **Column A** **Sheet 2** with **Column A** **Sheet 1** and returns `TRUE` & `FALSE` & if not found returns `#N/A`

[image]

---

• `=(E3:E5=B3:B6)` Again, we are trying to match between **Column B** of both the sheets and which returns `TRUE` & `FALSE` & if not found returns `#N/A` respectively.

[image]

---

• Next, we are multiplying both the **Boolean** Values from the above to see whether they are returning `1` & `0` or not, where `1` signifies `TRUE` while `0` signifies `FALSE` & we are taking those which are not one's

```
=((D3:D5=A3:A6)*(E3:E5=B3:B6))<>1
```

[image]

---

• As the above is returning `#N/A` for the one which is not found, therefore we are wrapping the whole of the above within an `IFNA()` so whcih checks for the error and returns `TRUE`

```
=IFNA(((D3:D5=A3:A6)*(E3:E5=B3:B6))<>1,TRUE)
```

[image]

---

Finally `FILTER()` Function returns the array only when there is `TRUE`

[image]

---

```
=FILTER(A3:B6,IFNA(((D3:D5=A3:A6)*(E3:E5=B3:B6))<>1,TRUE))
```

---

For those using Excel 2010/2013/2016/2019, can try using with `INDEX()` & `AGGREGATE()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `K3`

```
=INDEX($A$3:$B$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,
(ROW($A$3:$B$6)-ROW($A$3)+1)/
(COUNTIFS($D$3:$D$5,$A$3:$A$6,$E$3:$E$5,$B$3:$B$6)=0),ROW(A1)),0)
```

---

**Note:** Since I have shown in the same worksheet instead of multiple sheets you may need to change the ranges and sheet names are per your data accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much - this looks to be what I need, but I cannot get the "Filter" formula to work. I think my version of excel is too old so I am going to see what I can do to update it. Thank you!

Comment: @Alanna What is your Excel Version?

Comment: I have Excel 2019

Comment: Is the ROW(A1) at the end correct? I still can't get this to work, but wow you are so helpful and I very much appreciate it

Comment: Please show a screenshot of how it is not working for you? As far I understand the sample data shown it works accordingly 

Comment: I added another post with a link to a screenshot. The cell is showing up as #VALUE! .. I tried using this on my actual data, but it wouldn't work so I tried setting it up with our exact example and this is what is coming out. Again - thanks so much

Comment: Yes, can you try pressing the `CTRL+SHFT+ENTER` may be older versions needs that, while exiting the edit mode

Comment: @Alanna if you are still facing the error, then simply try this: `=INDEX(A$3:A$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$3:$B$6)-ROW($A$3)+1)/(COUNTIFS($D$3:$D$5,$A$3:$A$6,$E$3:$E$5,$B$3:$B$6)=0),ROW(A1)),)` fill down and then fill right

Comment: So sorry - I am not the best at Excel. So yes, once I click CTRL+SHFT+ENTER I get "Bear" in that first cell, but no other cells populate. I can drag the cell down and it will spit out Panda below that, but I cant get the number to show up in column B. How do I get more than just the first cell to show up with data. This is beautiful - thanks again

Comment: Yes once you have filled down, and now fill right. or select the cells which are filled along with the cells on the right empty cells and press `CTRL + R`

Comment: Nevermind - I got it now. Yay! Thank you so much, you are amazing. I very much appreciate your help. Have a blessed day!

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you.